# Angular cast select value to int

Tags: forms, angular, casting

I have a form with different selects like :

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected.isConnected" (ngModelChange)="formChanged()" name="etat" id="etat" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Not connected</option>
    <option value="1">Connected</option>
</select>
```

My backend expect to receive an int in the "isConnected" attribute. Unfortunately as soon as I change the value of the select the attribute is cast to a string :

```
{
    isConnected : "0", // 0 expected
}
```

For standard `<input>` I could use `type="number"` but for a `<select>` I'm clueless.

Is there a way to force angular 2 to cast the data to int ?

Comment: would you please show `formChanged()` method?

Comment: Use ng-options. Using nested option will always set the model as a string. That's documented.

Comment: ng-option does not exist in Angular2. Maybe you mean using [ngValue] instead of [value].

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Use [ngValue] instead of "value":

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected.isConnected" id="etat">
    <option [ngValue]="0">Not connected</option>
    <option [ngValue]="1">Connected</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works and is as simple as would be expected from angular.

Comment: It does work in Angular 6.  Make sure the type of your `ngModel` and `ngValue` are both `number`.  Mine was failing b/c `ngValue` was a string.  (duh) @BrianLeach

Comment: This can also be used by AngularJs for anyone still using that... just remove the square brackets around the ng-value attribute.

Answer (score 4):

If you want cast it within **formChanged()** method (Which you haven't provided yet).
You should use **+ symbol** as shown below,

```
formChanged(): void {
    selected.isConnected = +selected.isConnected;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was hoping it was possible to tell angular to automatically parse it. But using formChanged() could indeed do the trick

Comment: What i did : this.selected.myKey = Number(this.selected.myKey);

Comment: You just need to put `+ sign`. Thats it !

Comment: Beware that this does not handle nulls, so an input of `"null"` will yield `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

No, sadly you're forced to parse it on your own in the `formChanged()` method, since you always get a string back from the `select`.

You could try it with something like this:

```ts
formChanged(): void {
    selected.isConnected = parseInt(selected.isConnected);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a Number variable to select and assign the value for that select element. Then if you want to capture the value when it changes, you can add (change) event to select and retrieve the value as shown below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<select value="{{isConnected}}" (change)="printConnected($event.target.value)" name="etat" id="etat" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Not connected</option>
          <option value="1">Connected</option>
        </select>
        <div *ngIf="changed">You've selected {{isConnected}}<div>`
})
export class AppComponent {

  isConnected : number = 1;
  changed : boolean = false;
  printConnected(value){
this.isConnected = value;
this.changed=true;
  }

}
```

You can view an example at http://plnkr.co/edit/xO2mrTdpTGufkgXqdhYD?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I am using reactive bindings and do not want to use `[(ngModel)]`. Instead I created a piped observable that uses `JSON.parse(value)` (because `+value` doesn't handle `"null"`):

*.component.html:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
      <label>Group Type</label>
      <select class="form-control" (change)="groupType$.next($event.target.value)">
        <option [value]="null"></option>
        <option *ngFor="let groupType of filterData.groupTypes" [value]="groupType.id">{{groupType.label}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 form-group" *ngIf="filteredGroups$ | async as groupOptions">
      <label>Group</label>
      <select class="form-control" (change)="group$.next($event.target.value)">
        <option [value]="null"></option>
        <option *ngFor="let group of groupOptions" [value]="group.id">{{group.label}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
      <label>Status</label>
      <select class="form-control" (change)="status$.next($event.target.value)">
        <option [value]="null"></option>
        <option *ngFor="let status of filterData.statuses" [value]="status.id">{{status.label}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

*.component.ts:

```
  group$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  groupId$ = this.group$.pipe(
    map((groupId: string) => JSON.parse(groupId) as number)
  );
  groupType$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  groupTypeId$ = this.groupType$.pipe(
    map((typeId: string) => JSON.parse(typeId) as number)
  );
  status$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  statusId$ = this.status$.pipe(
    map((statusId: string) => JSON.parse(statusId) as number)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

[ngValue] is intended for objects. It generates an artificial option value even for numeric constants. For those who might be concerned about tests or readability, you can expand two way binding microsyntax

```
    <select [ngModel]="selected.isConnected" 
            (ngModelChange)="selected.isConnected=$event && +$event" id="etat">
        <option value="0">Not connected</option>
        <option value="1">Connected</option>
    </select>
```