# Angular ModelDriven formModel map change value type ES6

Tags: angular, mapping, angular-reactive-forms, es6-modules, value-type

I have been following the [angular hero tutorial on model driven form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and I got an issue with mapping,

```
const secretLairsDeepCopy: Address[] = formModel.secretLairs.map(
    (address: Address) => Object.assign({}, address)
  );
```

with address define as

```
Address {
  street = '';
  city   = '';
  state  = '';
  zip    = '';
}
```

now  if decide for instance to set zip as a number and in the html make it select from a list when I save the address in the formModel I get zip as a string, and not a number even if I define zip as number and give a number in entrance, it is automatically changed to string.

I am not sure if it is due to angular or to es6 as .map is defined in lib.es6.d.ts

Thanks for reading,
have a great day !

EDIT:

I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1vbk5?file=index.html) as sample but the test is done on the State attribute and not the zip as I used the hero tutorial basis and State was already chosen from a list, it was faster to modify. 
So in this stackblitz I set the state list as a number list and initialize the state to a number.

EDIT:

Seems like it is due to 
    `<option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</option>`
Which have to be replaced by
    `<option *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state">{{state}}</option>`
cf [Angular 2 cast select value to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474188/angular-2-cast-select-value-to-int) as mentioned in the comment by Pierre Mallet

Comment: could you add snippets of your component / template with the list ?

Comment: [sample](https://github.com/Niradnik/angularMapChangeType/blob/master/reactive-forms-map-change-type.zip) made on the basis of hero tutorial from angular.io 
I set state as a number you can check it by clicking on save you will have an alert box that give the it's type.

Comment: the alert box show the type of address[0]['State']

Comment: could you export this in a stackblitz or plunker? To be honest I have no time to create an environment from your sources.

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1vbk5?file=index.html)

Comment: by default an input is of type text. So it will return a string. You can add the type number to your <input> but you will not be able to select zip code starting by a 0. So you have to make a manual parsing of the data before sending it to your API. BTW : never do that for a zip code if it can start with a 0, you will loose this information after parsing.

Comment: But first you will have to change the type of your zip attribute in your Adress Class ( zip: number )

Comment: Sorry I didn't re-write it but I made the number/string test for the State not the zip as it was faster it was already a selection from a list. 
I didn't change anything to Zip so I didn't expect to have a number as everything is in string.
So for the Sate I gave a list of number I to select from and I initialize the Sate to a number so it should give me a number.

To see that you just need to change lets say the name of the hero hit save the alert will say it is a number.
Then select a state from the list then hit save and state become a string even though you select from a number list

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474188/angular-2-cast-select-value-to-int . Use ngValue instead of value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 cast select value to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474188/angular-2-cast-select-value-to-int)

Comment: Using [ngValue] seems to correct the issue even if I don't understand why as I am using the Reactive/Model driven form and not the Template driven form so I don't see why I have to use ngValue
Anyway thanks seems to work

Comment: [ngValue] is an angular`ish value, where [value] bind the native value attribute of the option which is coerced to string. I can not explain better without looking a the code