# How change [key: string] value to number in dropdown list?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

**HTML code**

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <select formControlName="Type" >
        <option value=0 >Related To The Team</option>
        <option value=1 >Personal</option>
        <option value=2 >Recommended By The Evaluator</option>
      </select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <select matNativeControl required formControlName="Attribute">  
        <option value=0 >Specific</option>
        <option value=1 >Measurable</option>
        <option value=2 >Attainable</option>
        <option value=3 >Relevant</option>
        <option value=4 >TimeBound</option>
      </select> 
    </mat-form-field>
```

**.TS code**

I tried with null and with number

```
      ngOnInit() {
      this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
      Type: [null],
      Attribute: Number['']});
```

my void

```
     onSubmit(): void{
     this.Service.add(this.Form.value)
     .pipe(first())
     .subscribe();
     console.log('test', this.Form.value);
     }
```

but it still return value:

```
    test Object { Type: "0", Attribute: "2"}
```

as string

how should I convert it?

Comment: so you want to convert a string to int? Use `parseInt`

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42997423/7561290) is your answer.