# Force value type when Angular form binding

Tags: angular

We have a form in Angular that has a select that displays a list of items:

```
<select formControlName="koppelingTypeId" id="KoppelingTypeId" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Selecteer een type</option>
    <option [value]="koppeling.koppelingTypeId" *ngFor="let koppeling of koppelingen">{{koppeling.naam}}</option>
</select>
```

The type of the bound value `koppelingTypeId` is number. When requesting the value for the form control however, we always get it back as a string. When posting back to a .NET Core endpoint this isn't seen as a valid value and thus gives an error.

Is there a way to force the form to keep the value as a string?

Related, but slightly different. We also have several fields that require Guid values (enforced via Regex validator) which we want to have return `null` when the field is empty because it otherwise yields the same deserialization issue in .NET Core.

Thanks

Comment: Well, there is an answer for numbers. But I don't know if it works for all data types. Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474188/angular-cast-select-value-to-int/42997423). Oh, I see someone gave you similar answer below...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular cast select value to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474188/angular-cast-select-value-to-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`. That will keep the appropriate data type.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
    <select formControlName="selectCtrl" class="form-control">
    <option [ngValue]="null">Selecteer een type</option>
    <option [ngValue]="link.linkId" *ngFor="let link of links">{{link.name}}</option>
</select>
```

[Here's a stackblitz that shows it working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szmb9d)

Comment: You totally win the Internet! Quick question, do you also know of a way to make an empty textbox yield `null` as value instead of the empty string `''`?

Comment: Same idea, make sure to use [ngValue] and set the value to null - I've edited the code sample to demonstrate. The stackblitz also shows it working.

Comment: For the null value I meant when using a textbox. Check this blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyzqyc when you enter something in the textbox and then clear it again, the value becomes `''`. It'd like it to become `null` again.

Comment: AH I see, my mistake. Different element. In that case you could subscribe to the "valueChanges" event for that control and set the value to null. Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rxnda

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me, I ended up adding a custom validator function that checks if the control value === '' and if so uses the setValue function to set it to null. Seems to work. Not as pretty as say a directive imo, but I'll take it.